# Format Exception Error when inserting data into sql using a flutter app

Tags: php, sql, flutter, dart

There is an application that I am developing that works and is doing everything that I need it to do. The application gathers data from a text controller then it inserts the data through a php. I am getting an error message that has been bothering and not sure what I am doing work.

Error: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at line 2, character 1)

```
 postData() async {


 try {
   var urlWeb =
   Uri.parse('https://sqlfinalproject.000webhostapp.com/insert.php');
   final response = await http.post(urlWeb, body: {"name":nameField.text,"last":lastField.text});

   if(response.body.isNotEmpty) {

     json.decode(response.body);

   }

 }
 catch (e) {

   print(e);

 }
```

}

Comment: This usually indicates a PHP script error or warning. Print out `response.body` before trying to decode it. Since PHP error / warning messages are not valid JSONs, `json.decode` will throw a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

try to below code one line changes :
import 'dart:convert';

```
postData() async {
  try {
    var urlWeb = Uri.parse('https://sqlfinalproject.000webhostapp.com/insert.php');
    final response = await http.post(urlWeb, body: {"name": nameField.text, "last": lastField.text});

    if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
     
      final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
     
    } else {
   
      print('Empty response from the server.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    
    print('Error occurred: $e');
  }
}
```